# change data in recycler view with click of button

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I am trying to create a challenge game where you can have 2 options to pick from, I have 2 card views setup in a recycler view setup, how would I change the values in them to get a new challenge with the click of a button from the main activity if a user wanted a new challenge?
I am fetching the data from each battle at random using an SQLite database.

My onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = faceMashDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("images", new String[]{"id","filename","name"},null,null,null,null,null);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
        int position1 = (int)(Math.random()*(faceMashDatabaseHelper.getCount()-0+1)+0);
        cursor.moveToPosition(position1);
        String filename = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("filename"));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        CardView cardView = myViewHolder.getCardView();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView nameView = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        nameView.setText(name);
        File file = context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
        if(file.exists()){
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = nameView.getText().toString();
                listener.onClick(position,name);
            }
        }); //This on click is for the card views themselves.



    }
```

My onClick at the current moment, I'm using a toolbar option

```
case R.id.newbattle:
faceMashAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never do heavy work in `onBindViewHolder` since it will be called every time your View is recreated after it was recycled (because it was unused).

You should query your Database outside of the Adapter instead and occupy a List with your queried data. Your List should have as many entries as your `RecyclerView` has entries. Then you can use the `position` parameter in `onBindViewHolder` to always get the correct data for the entry (`list.get(position)`).

This way you can just change the content of your List and notify the Adapter which items have changed via `notifyItemChanged` (or if all items should be refreshed, use `notifyDataSetChanged`). That way the content of the Adapter is refreshed.

So what you should do in your `onClick` is update the content of your List and notify the Adapter.

Comment: Did this help you? If yes, could you mark it as the solution, if not, what's the issue?